# How to build a Dialogflow CX agent with open questions?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I am trying to build a Dialogflow agent for something like StackOverflow, where it takes care of the user asking a complete question. I want to store the answer (and feed it back to the user). For example:

```
User: "I get an error."
CX: "Which error?"
"Java.lang.NullPointerException"
"Okay, what have you tried so far to solve this problem?"
"I googled it but found no results..."
"On what line of code do you get the error?"
"if (running) {counter ++}"
"Okay, so to summarize:
 - You got the error Java.lang.NullPointerException
 - You tried: I googled it but found no results...
 - You got the problem on the line of code:  what line of code do you get the error?
Is that correct?"
```

With no 'Fallback Intent'-hack available in CX; how would I go about building a bot with open ended questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the following response to your comment [How to build a Dialogflow CX agent with open questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64336721/how-to-build-a-dialogflow-cx-agent-with-open-questions#comment114153048_64362086)

To work with open ended (meaning: open answers that cannot be categorized into intents / parameters) questions, and store answers, you can use the same approach provided in my previous response, and utilize the “sys.any” entity and [parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter).

To do this:

1. When you create an [intent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/intent) for the utterances, annotate the
   utterances to the “sys.any” entity. Here is a sample for your
   reference:
   [image]

   You can change the name of your *parameter-id* to distinguish the parameters that you will use in each page.
2. Add those parameters on each page. Here is the sample for your
   reference:
   [image]
3. Continue applying *Step 1 & 2* to your other intents and pages for the
   collection and storage of answers to your open-ended questions.
4. When you have reached your final page, you can reference your
   parameters in the responses through this format:
   `$session.params.parameter-name`. Here is the sample for your
   reference:
   [image]

   You can check out [reference session parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter#session) for more information.

   When this is completed, this is how your use case similarly looks like:
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

To build a bot with open ended questions in Dialogflow CX, you can utilize the [Flows](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/flow) and [Pages](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/page) features.

As an overview, Flows are used to define your topics and its associated conversational paths. For each flow, you can define many pages, where your combined pages can handle a complete conversation on the topics the flow is designed for.
You configure each page to collect information from the end-user that is relevant for the conversational state represented by the page.
Once a page becomes active, the agent follows several steps which may involve entry fulfillment, pre-filling forms, state handler evaluation, form parameter prompting, sending response messages to the end-user, and either a page change or a repeat loop.

For your use case, you can create a flow for the user getting an error and pages for the error details.
To do this:

1. Create an [intent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/intent) for the utterance “I get an error”.
2. Add this intent as an [intent route](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#route) in your flow.
3. In the same intent route, create a new page for the error.
4. Under the Page’s [Fulfillment](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment), you can add your response as shown
   below:

[image]

This approach will leave an open ended question. See the test result below:

[image]

5. Continue the flow by creating another [intent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/intent) for the utterance
   “`Java.lang.NullPointerException`”.
6. Add the intent as an [intent route](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#route) in your page for the error(As an
   example: The page for the error is named “Error Types” and the
   intent name in Step#5 is “Java Error” as shown below):

[image]

7. In the same [intent route](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#route), create a new page for the
   “`Java.lang.NullPointerException`” (As an example, the page named is
   “Java Error Type” as shown below):
   [image]
8. Under the Page’s [Fulfillment](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment), you can add “Okay, what have you tried
   so far to solve this problem?” as the response.
9. Continue the flow by applying the same approach to your other open
   ended questions.

   When this is completed, this is how your use case similarly looks like in the visual builder:
   [image]

   See the test result below:

[image]

Comment: That is indeed how flows and intents work but does not really answer the question: how to work with open ended (meaning: open answers that cannot be categorized into intents / parameters) questions...

Comment: Can you clarify if you wanted to have bot responses that uses conditional logic depending on the free-form text received from the end-user or if you wanted to have bot responses to be hardcoded (i.e. The bot responses will always be the same and in the same order no matter what the end-user said)?

Comment: No conditional logic! Just storing answers.